# dpkt throws NeedData on valid pcap

Tags: python, pcap

I have this python code:

```
import sys
import dpkt

f = file("pcaop.Pcap")
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

i = 0
for ts, buf in pcap:
    print "Ya"
```

dpkt throws NeedData on the 52nd packet. The same one every time - I've checked packet 52 and it is the same as everyone else on wireshark.

What causes this?

Comment: Can you post a link to the pcap file as well as a Python program that [actually demonstrates the problem](http://sscce.org)? Without either, there's really nothing anyone can do to analyze or even fix the problem.

Comment: It's an internal company network pcap...

Comment: Actually it seems to throw that exception on every pcap I give it... Could it be a wireshark thing?

Comment: Well, you don't need to give us the exact same file you're having the problem with - all we need is *any file that demonstrates the problem*. How about a file that just contains the problematic packet? If that's still a problem, consider capturing a non-sensitive packet stream.

Comment: BTW: I'm using Windows 7, and this code works on linux

Comment: Oh, you should've said that in the first place - that completely changes the answers we can give. Are you using the same dpkt version and supporting libraries on both systems?

Comment: I should've checked that - I'm using dpkt 1.6 and python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu, and dpkt 1.7 with python 2.7 on windows. Though installing dpkt 1.6 on the windows machine causes the python script to fail with internal dpkt errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is provided here: [Python stops reading file using read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440819/python-stops-reading-file-using-read)
I had the same problem when dpkt.pcap was working fine under Linux but failed instantly when run in Windows.
The problem is that when a file is opened in text mode `open("filename", "r")` the file is read until EOF is encountered. Thus, `open("filename", "rb")`

Comment: I haven't tested it since I don't have the code & packets anymore - But I'm marking this as the answer... Thanks!