# problem with startswith() parsing big text-files in python

Tags: python, parsing, fasta

I am trying to learn python and I wanted to write a text-parser. I try to parse a large fasta-file full of dna-strings (it is 136275 lines long and has the size of 9.8MB).
My problem is that the program always stops working at an exact position (line 16076) and doesn't throw an error.

```
def file_parser(filepath):
  data = []
  file_content = open(filepath, 'r')
  line = file_content.readline()
  i=0
  while line:
    if line == 0:
      break
    elif line[0] == ">":
      key, name = line.split('|')[-2:]
      dna = ''
      line = file_content.readline()
      i = i+1
      while not line.startswith('>'): #line[0] != ">": #
        dna = dna + line
        line = file_content.readline()
      dna = dna.rstrip('\n')
      name = name.rstrip('\n')
      row = {
        key, 
        name, 
        dna
      }
      data.append(row)
      print(i)
    else:
      print("Your file is corrupted")
  return data
```

So my question is (as a beginner to writing python) whats wrong with my code that it stops working?
I assume that it could be the `line.startswith('>')` because I switched it to that because I had some string index out of range errors before but to be honest I'm not really sure.

My test-file comes from this source: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/Acanthisitta_chloris/protein/
(its the .fa.gz-file)
I use the a slightly customized Ubuntu 18.10 and python3.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't say a file is "large" without supporting that with a concrete number. I don't want to download a potentially *very* large file just to check.

Comment: @usr2564301 Ohh, yeah, forgot that, thank you.

Comment: Thanks! 9.8 Mb is not large at all (I process mutilples of that with eaze), so it should not be stressing Python, or your system in general.

Comment: Don't use `readline()` and a `while` loop. Just loop over the file object to get lines: `for line in file_content:`, and you can get additional lines in the loop with `next(file_content)`.

Comment: Are your running this on Windows perhaps? What Python version are you using?

Comment: @usr2564301 hrmm, okay, thanks. I thought that this could be a breaking point cause if I only want the first 20 entrys, the script works.

Comment: Not sure why you are creating rows as *sets*, those are not ordered structures. How do you distinguish between `key`, `name` and `dna` now?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, a customized Ubuntu 18.10 and python3.
(I'll add that to my question)

Comment: The code here has otherwise no issues with large files. It's probably the *file itself*, e.g. Windows will actually stop reading data from a file [when there is a specific character in the file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440819/python-stops-reading-file-using-read).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I checked that and didn't saw anything. (also tested another file)
Also yeah, the type of the rows is not optimal but I wanted to get the parsing-part working fully at first.

Comment: Side note: why parse this manually, when [BioPy has excellent Fasta support](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO)? There is also [this post on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/710/) with more code than you can shake a stick at to parse Fasta.

Comment: @MartijnPieters already saw that great BioPy-work but thanks.
I try to do it for the learning-purpose.

Comment: @MartijnPietersthe solution with the for loop works more or less (my main problem is solved), thank you very much. You could write it as an answer, so I can mark it as solution?